# using Cassandra or MongoDB to store complex JSON structures and enable search

Tags: json, mongodb

I am a newbie with the NoSQL trend and I need to start using it in a new JAVA project I am working on for storing my users' data from Facebook and\or other social networks to make some analysis and provide them with better results from my product.

The reason I want to use NoSQL over RDBMS is that the various APIs return the data in a form of JSON which is for me an unstructured data and I just need to persist it for a later use by analysis system. You can think of my reader as a dummy layer that only executes specific API and stores the response.

For example I have the following response:

```
{
   "oauth_token": "<ACCESS_TOKEN>",
   "expires": <EXPIRATION_TIME>,
   "name": "..."
   "gender": "...",
   "birthday": "...",
   "email": "...",
   <MORE FIELDS>
}
```

I am trying to think whether any of those solutions (Cassandra, MongoDB) can help. It I try to "format" the response and store each JSON key as a column it is quite similar to using RDBMS columns to enable search bu fields.

But I feel like I am missing something here... Is it possible to store as a "key-value"

for example:
"user-id" -> [THE ABOVE RESPONSE]

and to make queries to search inside the JSON response.

I will appreciate your help and maybe you can also give me references to better understand data techniques.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either MongoDB or Cassandra to store your response and create index on high carnality like **oauth_token** or **some_id** to support faster queries. NoSQL is totally different from RDBMS, it's store the data in key-value pair as similar to JSON and doesn't support schema like RDBMS.

Let say MongoDB collection **data** (you can relate collection to table in RDBMS ) contain following document -

```
{
  "oauth_token": "<ACCESS_TOKEN>",
  "expires": <EXPIRATION_TIME>,
  "name": "..."
  "gender": "...",
  "birthday": "...",
  "email": "...",
}
```

Execute following code to create index on key **oauth_token** (suppose) -

```
db.data.ensureIndex({oauth_token:1})
```

Execute follwing code to see the index detail -

```
db.data.getIndexes()
```

Execute following query to fetch the  record using **oauth_token** -

```
db.data.find({oauth_token: <OAUTH_TOKEN>})
```

You can refer to MongoDB documentation for more detail-

1. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/
2. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/
3. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your quick reply. I actually consider to use Cassandra as a requirement. I am just wondering how to parse it into the DB. Let's assume I insert key=[user_id] and value=[the json from the response] then the inner JSON fields are actually not "columns" of the cassandra but are a value of 1 specific column. Am I wrong? How would you do it? will you parse the response and add each key in the JSON response as a column?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to store a key with value as json then MongoDB is a better fit in this scenario as by default MongoDB stores data in BSON(which is JSON + additional data types). Moreover you can dynamically query complex json out of the box using its Javascript like query language. If you use Cassandra you need to map json=>columns which is overhead. Moreover Cassandra does not have extensive querying capabilities of MongoDB.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I was actually wondering if there is really an overhead replacing the JSON response from Facebook API into a map which seemed more natural with MongoDB. Thank you for clearing it out. I heard some claiming it would be better to use couchbase over mongodb - do you have any experience with that?

Comment: I do, there is a problem of plenty with NoSQL DBs. It is important to understand which NoSQL DB can satisfy your requirements to the maximum. In your specific case MongoDB should be a good enough choice(Couchbase is similar to MongoDB in most ways except like it supports Master-Master config, which would not be a criteria in your case). Do accept the answer if you find it useful so that it will act as reference for others.

Comment: Thank you :) I will definitely check MongoDB for my needs.